# Is $\textbf{P}(A) – \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$ same as $\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(B)$. This sure holds good in sets where $A - B = A - (A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

In probability are the below expressions the same or different

1. $\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(B)$
2. $\textbf{P}(A - B)$
3. $\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$

Consider just the set theory $A - B$ would be equivalent to $A - A\cap B$. Not sure if the same holds when calculating probabilities

Comment: $2$ and $3$ are the same, and both are (in general) different from $1$.

Comment: (Oh shoot, this is probablity, not power sets ...)

Comment: This (the title) is only true in general when $B \subset A$, since then $P(A , B)=P(B)$.

Comment: Thanks Xiaomi and Robert for your comments. Those were helpful

Comment: Hint: $P(A)-P(B)$ could be negative.